# Is there a way to build a menu in the background and show it after it's done?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been looking for a way to load a menu in the background and show it after it has loaded. The issue is that when menus take a long time loading the user just sees a freeze on his screen and the new menu just appears instantly on the screen because the transition was hidden by the freeze.

I thought I probably needed some loading screen but I did not find any way to build a menu in the background.

I am currently using the function

```
Navigator.push(context, slideTransitionBuilder(
        menu: QuizMenu(),
        begin: Offset(0, -1),
        end: Offset(0, 0),
        duration: 300)
    ));
```

Where slideTransitionBuilder returns a PageRouteBuilder with a Slide Transition.

I have tried using schedulers and some kind of splash screens.

Comment: does `slideTransitionBuilder()` return `TransitionRoute` or one of its subclass? if so check `TransitionRoute.animation` and `secondaryAnimation` properties - that way you can detect when animations finish

Comment: You can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Knowing when the animation is done wouldn't really solve the issue. What i want is to run the animation after the widget has been built.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use FutureBuilder for this case. Widget building doesn't return any future for me to use.

Comment: *"What i want is to run the animation after the widget has been built."* - what animation? there is only one animation run by a framework - when you go from one route to another using `Navigator.push(...)`

Comment: The navigator runs a slide transition from one menu to another. But this transition freezes because of the time it takes to load the menu.